# Xamarin Forms - UWP - VSTS task to deploy through App center - Yaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Xamarin Forms solution with 3 platforms: iOS, Android and UWP. I have setup 3 corresponding apps on App Center.

Currently I can successfully build and deploy iOS and Android through VSTS tasks (all defined in a Yaml).

I'm trying to do the same for UWP. However, I cannot find a VSTS task to deploy UWP apps through App Center.

UPDATE

FYI, here are the iOS and Android deployment tasks (on different phases and host, one windows one mac):

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@0
    displayName: 'iOS Deployment'
    inputs:
        serverEndpoint: 'App Center'
        appSlug: '.....'
        appFile: '**/*.ipa'
        symbolsDsymFiles: '**/*.dSYM'
        symbolsIncludeParentDirectory: false
        distributionGroupId: '..............'
        releaseNotesInput: 'bla bla'

- task: AppCenterDistribute@0
    displayName: 'Android Deployment'
    inputs:
        serverEndpoint: 'App Center'
        appSlug: '......'
        appFile: '...../*.apk'
        symbolsIncludeParentDirectory: false
        distributionGroupId: '......'
        releaseNotesInput: 'bla bla'
```

Comment: Thank you for looking. Not sure I understand what you asked though. I added the deployment tasks for iOS and Android (as I'm talking about deployment and not build).

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how showing you deployment logs of iOS or Android would help me find the correct UWP vsts deployment task?

Comment: Not the correct doc. This is about using app center SDK within the app which I already do. I wand to deploy through App Center via a vsts task as I do for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately we do not currently support Xamarin UWP build in App Center and have no eta at this time.

But please check our [roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/roadmap) that is updated frequently when we release updates.

**Update**

For deployment, you could select `Universal Windows Platform` VSTS Task. The process of Xamarin.UWP similar as native UWP. But the `Binary file path` of **Deploy to Visual studio  App Center** need to be modified.

**eg:**

**Solution Name**: XamarinAppTest

**Binary file path**: XamarinAppTest.UWP_1.0.0.0_Test.appx

[image]

I have tested, it works in my side.

Comment: I'm talking deployment not build.